# Bootstrap Navbar Active Links

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using Visual Studio 2017 with the built in MVC template, I added to bootstrap.css to create a navbar that is along the left side of the screen on sm/md/lg and across the top on xs. The navbar looks like so

```
<div id="sidenav" class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-lg-2 navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-left nav-stacked">
<div class="col-xs-12 container">
    <!--Header-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        @Html.ActionLink("Menu", "Index", "Home", "Home", new { @class = "navbar-brand" })
    </div>
    <!--Content-->
    <div class="navbar-collapse">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="@Url.Action("Elements", "Home", "Home")">Elements</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added to bootstrap.js the following and made no other changes:

```
$('.navbar-nav li a').click(function (e) {
$('.navbar-nav li.active').removeClass('active');
var $this = $(this);
if (!$this.hasClass('active')) {
    $this.addClass('active');
}
e.preventDefault();
});
```

The problem seems to be with the e.preventDefault(), if I include it, the active list item will change, but navigation doesn't happen. If I remove it, the active item will clear, the clicked item will change color, navigation happens, but then the correct link will go back to normal and the original active link is active again.

Probably something small and stupid but what do I have wrong or what am I missing, thank you.

Comment: I don't think i understand the question, you tell what happens when you do such and such, but what you want to accomplish is not clear enough.

Comment: I also had some problems to understand what is your issue, it would be better if you simplify your question and let it clear what is the result you want to achieve. But a shot in the dark will be: add `collapse` class to the `div.navbar-collapse` letting it like this: `<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">`

Comment: Problem is I have a link that says "Home" that is set as active in html, then there's a link to navigate to a page called "Elements" As is, if I navigate to Elements, the link for it never becomes active unless in the js I include the line e.preventDefault but then that makes the link not go to the view.